# Tslint - type trivially inferred - Why is it bad practice to include the type here?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

In VSCode the linter , tslint, complains when I add the following code, with the type:

```
serverId: number = 10;
```

And gives the following message:

> [tslint] Type number trivially inferred from a number literal, remove
>   type annotation (no-inferrable-types)

When I remove the type 'number', the message goes away.

Why is it bad practice to include the type information here?

Comment: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-inferrable-types/ says "Explicit types where they can be easily inferred by the compiler make code more verbose."

Comment: You say more verbose like it's always a bad thing, sometimes more verbose is more clear.

Comment: @EricBrown-Cal more verbose is more clear when it would be ambiguous without it. Adding more code that provides no additional information is, by definition, cruft. `const thisIsAVariableContainingTheNumericIdOfTheServer: numberNotBooleanOrStringOrObjectOrArray = 10`

Answer (score 114, accepted):

It is not a bad practice, but `serverId: number = 10` is redundant, because `number` type is [inferred](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) when a property is assigned. This is what TSLint `no-inferrable-types` warns about:

> Explicit types where they can be easily inferred by the compiler make code more verbose.

Unless there is a chance that `serverId` property may be initially undefined but be defined later (for instance in `constructor` function), `number` can be safely omitted.

This approach works best with [`noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) option because this way there are no chances that a type will be omitted by mistake because it wasn't inferred.

Answer (score 55):

As was mentioned above, it's technically redundant and can be considered clutter. Personally I don't care for this opinion and prefer to have both the type and the value for a variety of specific minor workflow reasons and I don't consider it to be the level of clutter warranting a rule. If you want to disable it, here's how.

- open tslint.json
- find the "no-inferrable-types" attribute
- add `ignore-properties` to its array

relevant tslint docs
https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-inferrable-types/

Comment: defer to team consensus or leader.  not a hard and fast rule that will make or break your work.  however, in cases where refactoring is future concern, having the explicitness of the typing may save future bugs inherited when a careless copy-paste now infers an unintended type. https://effectivetypescript.com/2020/04/28/avoid-inferable/

Answer (score 51):

If you came here looking for an ESLint solution because [tslint is being deprecated](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534), add this rule to your ESLint config:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  rules: {
    // ...,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": "off",
    ...
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Worked like a charm.

Frankly, I find it dumb that this is even a thing to begin with. I'm using TypeScript; let me define explicit types. If I wanted inferred type declarations, I would be using JavaScript, which is what I want to avoid, hence me using TypeScript in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. Insane how it seems like you are the only person on the internet who knows this!

Answer (score 33):

This error is due to your configuration in `tslint.json` file.

Either just initialize your variable as

```
serverId = 10;
```

or

```
serverId: number;
```

or just set your configuration for the `no-inferrable-types` in your tslint.json file as

```
no-inferrable-types: false
```

Answer (score 6):

It is unnecessary, it does not provide any new information. It is basically a comment saying "10 is a number".

Comment: In this case you're correct.... However, there can be ambiguity with strings and booleans... ( good variable naming should be followed as well...  )

Answer (score 2):

This might be weird coming for this now, but I was getting the similar error and couldn't find the "no-inferrable-types" attribute in the tslint.json file of my angular app. 
I don't know why it didn't generate that in the first place but I had to insert it here

```
"rules": {
    **"no-inferrable-types": false,**
    "directive-selector": [
      true,
      "attribute",
      "app",
      "camelCase"
    ],
```

And then it worked like a charm!

P.S. This is for someone who might be wandering with the same issue as I did, or I might be wrong because no one in any of the solutions mentioned that this has to be added from our end in the json file.

Comment: Needs to be `"@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types"`

Answer (score 1):

It could be seen as noise. It's more important to type the non trivial parts

Answer (score 1):

in *tslint.json* file add or complete this rule:

```
"no-inferrable-types": [
  true,
  "ignore-params",
  "ignore-properties"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

as it's mentioned in the documentation (https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-inferrable-types/),

> TypeScript is able to infer the types of parameters, properties, and variables from their default or initial values. There is no need to use an explicit : type annotation on one of those constructs initialized to a boolean, number, or string. Doing so adds unnecessary verbosity to code -making it harder to read- and in some cases can prevent TypeScript from inferring a more specific literal type

you can easily write `serverId = 10` and typescript automatically considers  *serverId* as *number*.

Answer (score 0):

In **Angular v13+** add this rule in .eslintrc.json file to resolve this issue

```
"@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": [
      "error",
      {
        "ignoreProperties": true
      }
    ],
```